# How to convert the following time format (2014-10-05T22:25:00-07:00) into required date format in javascript

Tags: momentjs

I want to convert the given time into required time format in javascript using moment.js

```
moment('2014-10-05T22:25:00-07:00').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:ss Z');
```

I am tried the above code to get result "06-10-2014 3.30" but it returns "06-10-2014 10:00 +05:30"

Comment: What timezone are you currently in?

Comment: india time zone UTC+05:30

Comment: Your format for time is for hours and seconds. Did you want hours and minutes? .format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm Z')

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: Why would you be expecting 3:30?

Comment: Are you sure that +5.30 isn't already added in 10.00? i.e. The time isn't 4.30?

Answer (score 0):

The time you are passing in is

```
2014-10-05T22:25:00-07:00
```

which is 5:25am on the 6th of October, GMT. You're then outputting it using the timezone UTC+05:30, which should give:

```
06-10-2014 10:55:00 +05:30
```

Unfortunately, you've missed `mm` from your date string, so you are only seeing:

```
06-10-2014 10:00 +05:30
```

Simply change your date format to `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss Z` to correct this.